# Grouping data in mysqli_fetch_assoc function

Tags: php, mysql, loops, session, foreach

Im trying to work out how to display appointment information,

i have a table called appointments and im currently iterating through the results of the select query as such

```
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $_SESSION['slot'][$i] = $row['slot'];
            $_SESSION['date'][$i] = $row['date'];
            $_SESSION['firstname'][$i] = $row['firstname'];
            $_SESSION['lastname'][$i] = $row['lastname'];
            $i++;
       }
```

now i can display each result with

```
    foreach ($_SESSION['firstname']  as $value)
        {
            echo $value;
        }
```

which resuts in "James" "John" "Joe" etc

but i cant figure out how to display the information as a group since they all belong to the same appointment.

I want to able to display

John Johnson, 5th april, 2pm

Joe Jackson, 12th april, 9pm

etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the index of one of the session variables as the index for the others in your loop:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['firstname'] as $key => $value) {
    echo "$value {$_SESSION['lastname'][$key]}, {$_SESSION['date'][$key]} {$_SESSION['slot'][$key]}<br/>\n";
}
```

Comment: You might want to add an `<br>` in there Nick. I think the OP wants to print those out onto new lines (on screen), seeing what they posted.

Comment: Right on Nick :) And with the original `\n` in there, that'll make for some clean and neat HTML. But I'm sure you knew that ;-) *Cheers!*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I am a big fan of clean and neat! You can't be a good engineer without being a bit obsessive! :-)

Comment: I am too Nick. Ever since I viewed HTML source in something I made many moons ago, noticed that it was very hard to debug when coding in PHP and there's output as HTML from rendered directives. Debugging in more ways than one I might add. I'm sure many don't know/use this, but most serious coders do. It just makes sense using its common relative ;-)